# MediaElement.js setSrc not working for flash fallbacks on FF, IE7-8

Tags: javascript, flash, mediaelement, mediaelement.js

I've seen a few discussions about this, but no real answers. I've had a lot of success getting `mediaelement.js` working for me except that it simply will not let me `setSrc()` on flash fallbacks. This is a huge bummer after so much work.

For a little background I'm using `mediaelement-and-player.js` v2.1.9 and using their player's API to change the media src via `player.setSrc`. I'm playing audio MP3s.

I'm getting this error in FF Mac:

> this.media.setSrc is not a function

And this error in IE8 Win:

> SCRIPT445: Object doesn't support this action

I find it hard to believe that this wasn't fully tested given that it seems a base part of their API. I've seen some other issues about similar problems but again, no real answers.

Comment: Update: I have found a work around, though it's not without it's bugs it seems to work reasonably well. Please see my comments to the following discussion posted in mediaelement's github issues: https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/246

Comment: anyone with a clear solution on this?

Comment: didn't get the error above, but had to call 'pause()' before 'setSrc()', then everything worked for me

Comment: @Gluip If it's still actual to you, try [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357421/mediaelement-js-setsrc-not-working-for-flash-fallbacks-on-ff-ie7-8#23692984)

Answer (score 0):

You would need to add "flashmediaelement.swf" to your code.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. Solved it by adding non-empty `src` and `type="audio/mp3"` attributes:

```
<audio id="player" controls src="#" type="audio/mp3" preload="none"></audio>
```

Presence of `preload="none"` is recommended here, because without it the element will send an additional request to a current page's URL in an attempt to download the audio.

---

**Update:** found an alternative way, zero-length WAV file can be embedded in `src`, thus you may use `preload` attribute normally and stop worrying about that an unneeded request will be sent if a user will click the play button before you set normal `src`.

```
<audio id="player" controls type="audio/mp3" src="data:audio/wav;base64,UklGRiQAAABXQVZFZm10IBAAAAABAAEARKwAAIhYAQACABAAZGF0YQAAAAA=">
```

Don't worry about `type` and `src` incompatibility, because, according to [audio element specification](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-video-element.html#audio), `type` isn't legal attribute of `audio` tag at all (`type` is only a `source` tag's attribute), here it's placed only to fix MediaElement.js behavior.

Answer (score 0):

I answered a similar question on [github](https://github.com/johndyer/mediaelement/issues/1028). Here's my solution:

This occurs when the setSrc method is called too soon after initializing the mediaElement player. Due to the flash fallback the swf (and therefore its api methods) will not be available until the success event is fired. After that setSrc works fine in IE8..

I didn't want to set the initial source from within the success handler. Therefore I used a boolean var to check whether the success event had occurred. In my source setting method I check for its value and use recursiveness (with a setTimeout to prevent overkill) whenever the boolean var equals false.. Did the trick for me.

```
//create the tag
var video = $("<video>",{id:"videoElement",width:640,height:360}).appendTo('body');//jquery

var mediaElementInitialized = true 

//create the mediaelement
var mediaElement = new MediaElementPlayer("#videoElement",{
            /**
             * YOU MUST SET THE TYPE WHEN NO SRC IS PROVIDED AT INITIALISATION 
             * (This one is not very well documented.. If one leaves the type out, the success     event will never fire!!)
             **/
            type: ["video/mp4"],
            features: ['playpause','progress','current','duration','tracks','volume'],

            //more options here..

            success: function(mediaElement, domObject){
                mediaElementInitialized = true;
            },
            error: function(e){alert(e);}
            }
        );

var setSource = function(src){

    if(mediaElementInitialized == true){

         if(mediaElement){
            mediaElement.setSrc(src);
            mediaElement.play();
        }

    } else {
        //recursive.. ie8/flashplayer fallback fix..
        var self = this;
        setTimeout(function(){
            self.setSource(src);
        },100);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

```
var plugin = new MediaElementPlayer(#mplay_audio_p',
{
//...params...
});

var url="http://www.somesite.com/audiofile.mp3";

plugin.setSrc(url);
plugin.load();
plugin.play();
```